# What is the difference between getApplicationSupportDirectory and getLibraryDirectory?

Tags: flutter

As an Android developer, I am pretty familiar with native `getFilesDir` function, which is provided by path_provider's `getApplicationSupportDirectory`. I noticed for iOS there is another function called **`getLibraryDirectory`** with pretty similar description in path_provider's docs. **But the docs are not much clear about it.** What is its purpose and when to use this instead of `getApplicationSupportDirectory` (or `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory`)?

Answer (score 0):

**getLibraryDirectory** function is used when the application is supposed to store the persistent data like backup files or database. It is used in iOS devices as in android it is not supported and throws exception.

**getApplicationSupportDirectory** function is used for application data which probably resides inside Android folder in android devices. It can be used for both iOS and Android devices. If the path doesn't exists it will create the directory. All the data will be wiped out if application is uninstalled/removed.

Comment: Hi, I did read this in the documentation, but I don't understand the difference. getLibraryDirectory is for persistent data like backup files or database. getApplicationSupportDirectory is for application data, which for me is also a database and some backup files 